# SQL Server 2008 data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

I have been trying to work on Northwind database for days, and when I created a DW_Northwind 'based on constellation diagram' thaT's what happened:

```
create database DW_Northwind2
go
-- table de fait 1
create table TF_LIV_CMD
(   ID_client    nchar(5),
    ID_Employee  int,
    Mois         datetime,
    Année        datetime,
    NB_CMD_LIV   int,
    NB_CMD_NONLIV int   
)
go
-- table de fait 2
create table TF_Product
(   SupplierID int,
    CategoryID int ,
    PriceLevel varchar (50),
    StockLevel varchar (50)
    )
go
-- table de fait 3
create table TF_Client 
(   Country    nvarchar (15),
    City       nvarchar (15),
    OrderLevel varchar (50) ,
    SalesLevel varchar (50)
    )
go
-- table de fait 4
create table TF_CA
(   Année      datetime,
    Mois       datetime,
    ID_client  nchar(5),
    CategoryID int ,
    ID_product int
    )
go
-- table de fait 5
create table TF_RemisAcc
(   Année     datetime,
    Mois      datetime,
    ID_client nchar(5),
    Discount  real
)
go
-- creation des table de dimmension 
create table TD_client
(   ID_client   nchar(5),
    CompanyName nvarchar(40),
    Country     nvarchar (15),
    City        nvarchar (15)       
)
go
Create table TD_Employee
(   ID_Employee int,
    LastName    nvarchar (20),
    FirstName   nvarchar (20),
    Country     nvarchar (15),
    City        nvarchar (15)
)
go
create table TD_Mois
      ( Mois datetime)
go
create table TD_Année
      ( Année datetime)
go
create table TD_Supplier
(   SupplierID  int,
    CompanyName nvarchar(40),
    Country     nvarchar (15),
    City        nvarchar (15)
    )
go
create table TD_Category 
(   CategoryID   int ,
    CategoryName nvarchar (50)
    )
go
create table TD_Country 
        (   Country nvarchar (15))
go
create table TD_City
(    City   nvarchar (15))
go
create table TD_Product 
(   ProductID   int,
    ProductName nvarchar (40)
    )
go


Alter table TF_LIV_CMD 
    add Constraint  FK_TF_LIV_CMD  Foreign key (ID_client)    references   TD_client   ( ID_client );

 Alter table TF_LIV_CMD 
    add Constraint  FK_TF_LIV_CMD1  Foreign key (ID_Employee)  references   TD_Employee ( ID_Employee );
Alter Table TF_Product
   add Constraint  FK_TF_Product  Foreign key (SupplierID)   references    TD_Supplier ( SupplierID );
Alter Table TF_Product
   add Constraint       FK_TF_Product1  Foreign key (CategoryID)   references   TD_Catgoery ( CategoryID );
Alter Table TF_Client
   add Constraint  FK_TF_Client   Foreign key (Country)      references    TD_Country ( Country );

Alter Table TF_Client
   add Constraint FK_TF_Client1   Foreign key (City)         references   TD_City    ( City);
Alter Table TF_CA
     add Constraint  FK_TF_CA      Foreign key (ID_client)     references    TD_client   ( ID_client );
Alter Table TF_CA
     add Constraint FK_TF_CA1      Foreign key (CategoryID)    references   TD_Catgoery ( CategoryID );

 Alter Table TF_CA
     add Constraint FK_TF_CA2      Foreign key (ProductID)     references   TD__Product ( ProductID );
Alter Table TF_RemisAcc
    add Constraint  FK_TF_RemisAcc     Foreign key (ID_client)     references    TD_client ( ID_client );

 Alter Table TF_RemisAcc
    add Constraint  FK_TF_RemisAcc1     Foreign key (Mois)          references   TD_Mois      ( Mois );

 Alter Table TF_RemisAcc
    add Constraint  FK_TF_RemisAccs2    Foreign key (Année)         references   TD_Année     ( Année );

Alter table TD_client
    add Constraint  PK_Client      Primary Key NonClustered ( ID_Client);

Alter table TD_Employee
    add Constraint  PK_TD_Employee Primary Key NonClustered (ID_Employee);

Alter table TD_Mois
    add Constraint  PK_TD_Mois        Primary Key NonClustered (Mois);

Alter table TD_Année
    add Constraint  PK_TD_Année       Primary Key NonClustered (Année);

Alter table TD_SUpplier
    add Constraint  PK_TD_SupplierID  Primary Key NonClustered (SpplierID);

Alter table TD_Category
    add Constraint  PK_TD_CategoryID  Primary Key NonClustered (CategoryID);

Alter table TD_Country
   add Constraint  PK_TD_Country      Primary Key NonClustered (Country);

ALter Table TD_City
  add Constraint  PK_TD_City          Primary Key NonClustered (City);

Alter table TD_Product 
  add Constraint  PK_TD_Product    Primary Key NonClustered (ID_Product);
```

error:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
There is already an object named 'TF_LIV_CMD' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TF_Product' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TF_Client' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TF_CA' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TF_RemisAcc' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_client' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'TD_Employee' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_Mois' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'TD_Année' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_Supplier' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_Category' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_Country' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TD_City' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'TD_Product' in the database.
Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'TD_client'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 38
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: The errors are self-explanatory: the objects already exist.

Comment: Did you google 'SQL Server There is already an object named...'?

Comment: yup, I did that before, and  it says that I have to drop the table before I creat it, but there no reason to drop if it doesn't exist already ps: I'm creating a new database not manupilating an old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects already exist in the database.

Put this for each table at the top of your query and you should be fine

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TF_LIV_CMD', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.TF_LIV_CMD;
```

Comment: thanks, you are the man .... plenty of errors lol but after all -- Command(s) completed successfully. --